# Move and replace if same file name already exists in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

```
${response14}=    Get WebElements    xpath=//*[@id="com_ibm_team_rtc_foundation_web_ui_views_ArtifactListView_4"]
Log    ${response14}
${txt1}=    Get Text     ${response14} 
create file     time1.txt    ${value_1}${txt}\n\n${value_2}${txt1} 
Log    ${txt1}
```

Here when i run the script , time1.txt file is created and contents will be stored,
but for me when i try to run again the same script again, i am getting error file already exits.
I don't want to give the different file name every time, and it should delete the previous file and store it again the new content, how to solve this in Robot framework
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the file before:

```
${response14}=    Get WebElements    xpath=//*[@id="com_ibm_team_rtc_foundation_web_ui_views_ArtifactListView_4"]
Log    ${response14}
${txt1}=    Get Text     ${response14}
remove file     time1.txt
create file     time1.txt    ${value_1}${txt}\n\n${value_2}${txt1} 
Log    ${txt1}
```